# iOS : check Settings - Accessibilty - Audio Description property programmatically

Tags: ios, audio, accessibility

I would like to programmatically check the property regarding Audio Description in iOS Accessibility settings.

I know that iOS expose some properties regarding Accessibility settings https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility

but I'm not able to find a property for the Audio Description setting.

Anyone knows where to find this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to programmatically check the property regarding Audio Description in iOS Accessibility settings.

It's actually **not possible in iOS 13** yet.

The complete list of a11y options that are programmatically available can be found hereunder:
[image]
Each one of these options is also detailed in the `Description` sheet of this [a11y website section](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/criteria-ios.html#accessibility-options) if need be.

Unfortunately, **the properties in the settings menu aren't all made available to the developers**.

Answer (score 0):

Just checking in to see if this is possible in iOS 15+ ?  I have a unique use case where I'm merging audio descriptions from .mp3's with the original .mp4 audio into an AVMutableComposition and I would like to take advantage of the built-in audio description setting instead of adding a custom toggle to the video player controls

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to read / listen to audio description system settings by using [MediaAccessibility](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaaccessibility/) framework

This is how to listen to the change:

```
NotificationCenter
      .default
      .publisher(for: MediaAccessibility.kMAAudibleMediaSettingsChangedNotification as Notification.Name)
      .sink { [weak self] _ in
        self?.handleAudibleMediaSettingsChangedNotification()
      }
      .store(in: &cancellables)
```

This is how to read the current AD settings in system settings

```
private func handleAudibleMediaSettingsChangedNotification() {
    guard let array = MAAudibleMediaCopyPreferredCharacteristics().takeRetainedValue() as? [String],
          array.contains(MAMediaCharacteristicDescribesVideoForAccessibility as String)
    else {
      /// AD in system settings is OFF
      return
    }

    /// AD in system settings is ON
  }
```